# Adding an UIView over a MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, mkmapview

I am trying to put a button in the corner of my MKMapView to control whether the map stays locked on to the user's location. What I have in mind is to create a `UIView` with a button on and add it over my `MKMapView` (not as an annotation or something) I can't figure this out with Interface Builder.

How can I add this button programmatically?

*Controlling whether it actually follows the user etc. is already sorted - just need the button for it.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are directly setting the controller's `view` outlet to an `MKMapView` object rather than a `UIView` object containing the `MKMapView` object. You cannot drop the button in such case on top of the `MKMapView` object in the `IB`. There are two ways you can deal with this,

1. Declare an outlet for the button and drop the button in the `IB`. This needn't be on top of the `MKMapView` object. Set the outlet to, say, a `button` property. Then in `viewDidLoad` do `[self.view addSubview:self.button];` after setting the `button`'s `frame`. (or)
2. Drop a new `UIView` object in IB and put the `MKMapView` object inside it. Set the controller's `view` to this container `UIView` object. Later drop the button on top of the `MKMapView` object and set it to its appropriate location.