# Interaction with map not working when adding subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to add a view with a couple of buttons to a map view. But when I do, I can no longer interact with the map below. Is there a way to keep the map interaction - and the interaction with the view on top of it - both alive?

This is what I'm doing:

```
TextAdd *textAdd = [[TextAdd alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 320, 120)];
textAdd.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:textAdd];
```

This creates a strip at the bottom of the iPhone screen - and the map doesn't respond when tapping, or pinching it at that area. I also tried to add the textAdd directly to the mapView:

```
[self.mapView addSubview:textAdd];
```

but the result is the same. So is there a way to do it? I know I can add my widgets directly to `self.view` and then everything works, but the thing is that I need to recycle my textAdd and want to write it once, and not for every ViewController in my app.

EDIT: the implementation of my TextAdd class. Very simple:

TextAdd.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TextAdd : UIView

@end
```

TextAdd.m:

```
#import "TextAdd.h"

@implementation TextAdd

UIButton *addText;
UIView *addingTextView;
UIButton *edit;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        addText = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        addText.frame = CGRectMake(110, 340, 140.0, 40.0);
        [addText addTarget:self action:@selector(showTextWidget) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [addText setTitle:@"Add/Edit Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:addText];
}

    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: What does your `TextAdd` class look like? What is it derived from, and does it override anything like `pointInside:` or `hitTest:`?

Comment: It's a UIView. @interface TextAdd : UIView

Comment: Is the implementation long? Could you add it to your question?

Comment: I added it. But it's straightforward, I think.

Comment: First, you should move your variables into your `@interface` declaration as ivars. Second, it looks like you're missing part of your `init` method. There's no reference to `addingTextView` or `edit`, and you don't have a `return self`.

Comment: Maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391080/adding-an-uiview-over-a-mkmapview

Comment: godel9 I added the end of the init method to the question, and in my code moved the ivars to the interface. But these don't really do anything regarding my question. Tomer, thanks but it doesn't.